# How to build and test Xcode iOS SDK 4.3 project in iPad 2 iOS 5?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

I'm wondering if I can build and test my current project which is **iOS SDK 4.3** based, to **iPad 2 (iOS 5)**? In **Organizer - Devices** it says:

```
The version of iOS on “my iPad” does not match any of the versions of iOS
supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore
the device to a version of the OS listed below, or update to the latest version
of the iOS SDK;
```

Can I build my project without updating to iOS SDK 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isnt possible, you must upgrade to the lastest Xcode.

It is possible to have two versions of Xcode installed if you still want to hang onto the old one.

What is the reluctance to upgrade?  Are you having compiling issues?

Comment: I installed new xcode with iOS SDK5, my previous projects works fines. Thx